# Do all organisms have to die?

Tags: senescence, death

I understand (a little) that there are biological clocks and reason that after a certain amount of time organisms die. I'm wondering if that is something inherent in our DNA or in biology/chemistry in general. EG, is it possible that there could be a complex organism that would not die and would just regenerate it's cells In Perpetuam? I'm specifically interested in mammals and even more specifically interested in humans. But, I would be interested in hearing about other organisms like bugs, fish, plant, algae, etc.

I'm not asking if this practical, do we know how to do this, etc.. I just want to know theoretically if living forever is biologically possible, as far as we know. If not, is there an estimated upper limit?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_immortality

Comment: It's definitely not practical. Lets assume an organism had evolved past disease and aging. It would still eventually die because with infinite time, the odds of it eventually falling into a situation where it runs out of food, or gets eaten, or dies in an accident go to 100%. So even an immortal species would still need to reproduce. If birth rates remain normal, but death rates are much slower, the population would explode, leading to many problems with food supplies and space and environmental issues.

Comment: @user137 - I'm not considering about practicalities.

Comment: Given current world state (lifestyles, climates, environment, food and water resources) and health tech I'd suggest it's in the region of 130-140 years, not sure anyone has lived longer and with billions of people on the planet that's a pretty good sampling effort but then again I'm guessing no one has yet stumbled across the perfect combination of genes and lifestyle so maybe a little longer

Comment: [This interesting post](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17077/why-does-evolution-not-make-our-life-longer) is very much related

Comment: @user137 Might not be practical for the species, but evolution doesn't really care about species survival.

Comment: Are you also interested in bacteria and fungi that reproduce clonally? The situation is a bit different compared to higher animals.

Comment: @fileunderwater - no - I'm interested in the possible immortality of a single organism.  There may be similarities in how they deal with the [Hayflick limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayflick_limit), but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Yehosef "*single organism*" isn't that easy to define though. Do you consider [aspen clones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pando_%28tree%29) a single organism or not? They are considered as one of the oldest living organisms, and should be relevant to your question, even though they are in one sense a multicellular plant analog to bacterial clonal growth.

Comment: @fileunderwater - fair enough.. I'm more interested in animals, but it's interesting to see other examples like you mention.

Comment: According to Agent Smith (The Matrix series): `Everything that has a beginning has an end, Neo...`

Comment: @user137 This argument makes no sense. There is no reason why if an animal only died through accidents, its birth rate couldn't adapt to reflect this. All animals' birth rates are tuned in a feedback loop which reflects death rates at different life stages, whether by accident, disease or old age, fertility rates and the size of breeding populations, and the potential consequences of overpopulation.

Comment: @jwg assuming the organism developed immortality over a long time the birth rates would have time to adjust as well. But as human life spans have increased over the last century and infant mortality has been greatly reduced, birth rates tended to remain high for several years, leading to a large increase in the number of humans. This is relevant because there are some researchers who think they can develop immortality for humans. Which, if possible, would happen over a short time scale, and birth rates wouldn't adjust.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8176/do-immortal-organisms-exist?rq=1

Comment: related http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7010/is-there-any-kind-of-immortality-in-plants?lq=1, http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/6884/why-is-the-hydra-biologically-immortal

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [immortal jellyfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turritopsis_dohrnii) can revert back to its immature polyp stage after reaching maturity, then mature again, over and over. You can read more on the wikipedia page, but this ability means it can potentially avoid senescence altogether.

Comment: It too will die when the sun becomes a red giant.

Comment: @Joshua Technically, it will be boiled. But I can say this with certainty that it will surely die when you will disintegrate it into atomic particles. :P

Comment: @Joshua naturally, but it will fry, not senesce, and that's what the question is asking about ;)

Comment: The cited wiki page cites one iffy reference, but the other is good, and available online: http://www.biolbull.org/content/190/3/302.full.pdf+html  The authers of this article indeed claim that Turritopsis may be immortal (!!). Thanks for this great answer.

Comment: @Joshua It is considered Biologically immortal, meaning that it will not die as a result of cellular processes... That does not mean that an external agent can't kill it.

Comment: @Joshua Well, if someone took such Jellyfish into an aquarium in a spaceship and took it to another solar system, then it could go on living. But of course, any such activity would probably eventually fail.

Comment: Won't most bacteria be biologically immortal as well? If food wasn't a limitation.

Answer (score 6):

You have a very interesting question there!

In order to answer, however, we must examine the most widely accepted "reason" for why we age and eventually die. Most scientists agree that it is because of mass cell death. Normally you and I would be able to deal quite well with mass cell death (such as a very large injury), the problem comes in when we are older because we *cannot* replenish them because we have physically exhausted our own supply of something called stem cells.

Most cells in our bodies actually cannot divide, so they rely on these stem cells (which can divide into any cell; think of them as a wild card) to replenish whatever cells die.

Sounds perfect, right? Not quite, each of us only have a given number of stem cells in our body (even though stem cells can divide into more stem cells, they usually don't). So the reason we age and die is because we "run out", if you will, of these stem cells and our supply of cellular replenishment is slowly cut off.

Back to your question, is it possible to stop this? Well you've probably already come to this conclusion by now, but *theoretically* if you could somehow supply the body with a constant number of stem cells, theoretically, you could live forever (or at least a *really* long time). This is evident, as you are aware, in flatworms, who have stem cells constantly circulating their bodies and are practically immortal.

Comment: Why do you call "running out of stem cells" the reason we die? It can just as easily be a side effect.

Comment: Sorry? Side effect of what?

Comment: Death process..

Comment: That's what I have found to be the reason for aging in the time that I have studied it.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm only saying that it is one reason for death, not all. Death can be caused by many things.

Comment: I know we study a lot of things that are not proven yet. I can remember things from my first biology books that we can laugh about now. That's when I try to bring as much logic in the game as I can. The fact is, we are not born with a fixed amount of stem cells. They grow and multiply rapidly at young age. And then at some point, you can observe a change of direction, instead of increasing, the amount of stem cells starts to decrease. Something causes this.

Comment: And I do not profess to know the answer to that, thus why I said it was theoretical. Of all the studies I have done this would most likely be the most mysterious, we know that we stop producing the chemicals needed to stimulate stem cell division as we get older, but beyond that we really don't know. It almost appears to be programmed into us, as if on purpose. I don't know how much Yehosef is wondering about the reason for aging though, and I was just presenting an idea on how to stop it (with a bit of needed scientific background for him to understand the idea of course).

Comment: Running out of stem cells seems more like an answer to "how" than to "why".

Comment: His question was regarding how immortalization could occur, therefore only a "how" answer was required, therefore that's all I gave.

Comment: Interesting - I thought that most cells can divide, its just that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayflick_limit that limits how often before the DNA becomes too damaged (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senescence).  Meaning, it seems that the cells stop dividing after a while but new stem cells can take their place and make new cells.  So if you can either stop the DNA damage via expression of telomerase (see lobster longevity) or by generating adult stem cells to regenerate cells that can no longer divide.  Either of these might work.

Comment: With many cells that is the case, however the cells I was speaking of are generally those that don't divide, such as nerve cells, brain cells, heart (muscle) cells and blood cells and those cells that rarely divide, such as liver and kidney cells. I suppose that stem cells would replenish those cells that are nearing or have reached the Hayflick limit merely by slowly replacing them with cells that have fresh DNA.