# Hydra immortality

Tags: senescence

Recent research on immortality ha been on an organism named Hydra. I have heard about it being related to some FoxO gene, which has been found in several other organisms but how does telomerase affect the immortality of this amazing species?

Comment: @Dexter No, hydra is specifically investigated for its (presumed) lack of senescence, *not* just its regenerative abilities — unlike, say, planaria.

Comment: Yes, I realized. Just searched. You are right @KonradRudolph . I had no idea about this FoxO. I will delete that comment .

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/6884/why-is-the-hydra-biologically-immortal?rq=1

Comment: @AliceD no i find it incomplete..

Comment: @TanMath what do you find incomplete about it? Please [edit] your answer and clearly state *exactly* what you're looking for, and how the answers to existing questions, as well as other online resources, don't completely address what you're looking for.