# Can immortality of the Turritopsis dohrnii be learned or adapted by other species?

Tags: zoology, marine-biology

I have heard that Turritopsis dohrnii is a species of jelly fish which is immortal, as it can grow old and then back to growing young.

So, how is it possible?   Can other species (marine and/or land) species adapt or  evolve into such a system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the Hydra Biologically Immortal?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/6884/why-is-the-hydra-biologically-immortal)

Comment: @AliceD I had a look at that question, and I don't think this is a duplicate of it.  This asks whether some other species can adapt or evolve itself to have such features which helped Turritopsis dohrnii with the immortality characteristics

Comment: The answers of linked question answers the 'how' part and the theory whether other species could evolve such a system is opinion based and open-ended. Knowing how it works (stem cells, telomerase activity) can be extrapolated to other species, in theory and in theory only.